# If $L^{\infty}$-norm of a set of Holder continuous functions is bounded, then does it imply that its $L^p$-norm is also bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I have a set of real valued functions defined on a bounded open subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, such that each function $f$ is Holder continuous of modulus $\gamma\ge1-\frac{m}{p},p>m$. It is known that $$\|f\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \le \delta\forall f\in S$$ Can we say that there exists a $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $$\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\le \epsilon \forall f\in S$$

Answer (score 2):

$\|f\|_p \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \mu (\Omega)^{1/p}$ so we can take $\epsilon =\delta \mu (\Omega)^{1/p}$.

I have used $\mu$ to denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Comment: May I know what is $\mu(\Omega)^{1/p}$?, looks like its a constant depending only on $\Omega,p$. May I now what is this theorem called?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju I has used $m$ for Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb  R^{m}$ without realizing that you had used $m$ for the dimension of the space, I have now changed it to $\mu$. Since $\Omega$ is bounded, its Lebesgue measure is finite.

Comment: Could you please provide any reference for this theorem?

Comment: $\int_{\Omega} |f|^{p}d\mu \leq \int_{\Omega}  \|f\|_{\infty}^{p} d\mu = \|f\|_{\infty}^{p}(\mu (\Omega))$. Now rise both sides to power $1/p$. @RajeshDachiraju

Comment: Ah Thank you. got it.

Comment: So Holder continuity is not really needed here?

Comment: No! Just the definitions of $L^{p}$ and $L^{\infty}$ norms. @RajeshDachiraju